# How to remove ZERO WIDTH SPACE on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

When copy and paste the codes below from a book into an editor or Mac terminal, ZERO WIDTH SPACE having byte value 226 128 139 are inserted, resulting in SyntaxError unexpected token: "​" (column 22, code point U+200B).

For example, the two sentences below look identical, but NOT.

> Code (1). GenServer.call(pid, :next_number​)
>
> Code (2). GenServer.call(pid, :next_number)

Code (1) has ZERO WIDTH SPACE inside, but Code (2) not. Below are ASCII codes of the above.

> Code (1).71 101 110 83 101 114 118 101 114 46 99 97 108 108 40 112 105 100 44 32 58 110 101 120 116 95 110 117 109 98 101 114 226 128 139 41
>
> Code (2).71 101 110 83 101 114 118 101 114 46 99 97 108 108 40 112 105 100 44 32 58 110 101 120 116 95 110 117 109 98 101 114 41

As shown, Code (1) has 226 128 139 on its end.

It's quite troublesome. Is there any setting(bash or something) to remove ZERO WIDTH SPACE automatically from all files and terminal?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to remove the ZWSP upon pasting?

Comment: @slhck Yes, exactly. I am using Mac, so modifying a bash file is desirable.

Comment: You cannot do this simply by modifying a Bash file. Can you run `pbpaste | sed 's/\xe2\x80\x8b//g' | pbcopy` and see if that modifies your clipboard content to remote the ZWSP?

Comment: @slhck Thank you, Werner. I know that, but its a little cumbersome way. Anyway thank you again.

Comment: No worries. The only alternative I can think of is using a clipboard manager and possibly modifying it (i.e. some open source code such as https://github.com/Clipy/Clipy or https://github.com/snark/jumpcut) so that it runs the replacement before pasting.

Comment: @slhck Good alternatives, I will try them.